# Flutter: How do I fit the bound when google map is created and markers are being rendered

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-getx

I am using `GetX` with my application and I have following codes.

**View**

```
final MapPageController controller = Get.put(MapPageController());

Widget build() {
    size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff6f7f9),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading:
            (ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop ?? false) ? BackButton() : null,
        title: Text("MAP".tr),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.baseColor,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Obx(() => GoogleMap(
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(controller.allMarkers),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController gmcontroller) {
                _controller.complete(gmcontroller);
                _fitMapBounds();
              },
            )),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
}

Future<void> _fitMapBounds() async {
  final GoogleMapController gmcontroller = await _controller.future;
  gmcontroller.moveCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
      controller.boundsFromLatLngList(),
      size!.getSizePx(20),
    ),
  );
}
```

And my **Controller** `MapPageController`

```
class MapPageController extends GetxController {
    RxList<LatestPositions> latestPositions = <LatestPositions>[].obs;
    RxList<Marker> allMarkers = <Marker>[].obs;
    RxList<LatLng> latLngListForBound = <LatLng>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    await getRealtimePositions();
    await getMarkers();
  }

  Future getRealtimePositions() async {
    try {
      if (imeisForRealtime.length > 0) {
        Map params = {"Imeis": imeisForRealtime, "timezone": timeZone.value};

        var res = await CommonApiProvider.getRealtimePositions(params);

        if (res != null && res.status == "ok") {
          if (res.data.length > 0) latestPositions.clear();

          for (final data in res.data) {
            latestPositions.add(
              LatestPositions(
                  accuracy: data.accuracy,
                  sendTime: data.sendTime,
                  battery: data.battery,
                  speed: data.speed,
                  color: data.color,
                  deviceCode: data.deviceCode,
                  deviceName: data.deviceName,
                  longitude: data.longitude,
                  latitude: data.latitude,
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());

      rethrow;
    } finally {}
  }

  getMarkers() {
    for (final data in latestPositions) {
      var _marker = Marker(
          consumeTapEvents: true,
          markerId: MarkerId(data.trackerId.toString()),
          position:
              LatLng(double.parse(data.latitude), double.parse(data.longitude)),
          onTap: () {
            //do something here
          });

      allMarkers.add(_marker);
      latLngListForBound.add(
          LatLng(double.parse(data.latitude), double.parse(data.longitude)));
    }
  }


  LatLngBounds boundsFromLatLngList() {
    double x0 = 0;
    double x1 = 0;
    double y0 = 0;
    double y1 = 0;

    List<LatLng> list = latLngListForBound;

    for (LatLng latLng in list) {
      if (x0 == 0) {
        x0 = x1 = latLng.latitude;
        y0 = y1 = latLng.longitude;
      } else {
        if (latLng.latitude > x1) x1 = latLng.latitude;
        if (latLng.latitude < x0) x0 = latLng.latitude;
        if (latLng.longitude > y1) y1 = latLng.longitude;
        if (latLng.longitude < y0) y0 = latLng.longitude;
      }
    }
   
    return LatLngBounds(northeast: LatLng(x1, y1), southwest: LatLng(x0, y0));
  }

}
```

**Problem,**

Basically what I want is to make all marker(s) visible when map is loaded and markers are rendered.
I have called `_fitMapBounds()` on `onMapCreated` event. But it doesn't work on start, but when I hot reload the app, then it works.
Seems that map is rendered and `onMapCreated` event is fired before `getRealtimePositions()` method is fired in the `onInit` event of the controller.
How do I cope with this issue?

Thanks